Is an API deprecation warning considered an unbreakable contract?
I have an API that is about to move between MAJOR versions—from v1.x.y to v2.0.0.  It is following semver (though I don't think that really matters).
In version 1.x.y, I have several public constants and methods that I have deprecated.  Usage of them will show an appropriate deprecation warning that tells what should instead be used going forward.  However, this is presenting me a problem.  What I now intend to use for some of them is not what I previously "advertised" in the warning message.  And some others I've decided not to deprecate after all.
For example:

Deprecated constant

MyClass::ACTIVE - "DEPRECATION WARNING: MyClass::ACTIVE is deprecated.  Please use MyClass::ACTIVE_STATUS instead."  But I now want to name the updated constant something other than "ACTIVE_STATUS".


Deprecated method

MyClass::some_method - "DEPRECATION WARNING: ::some_method will change behaviour in version 2.0.0'".  But now I'm not positive I actually want to change the behaviour (partially because I can't remember what I wanted it to do different).



So by "strict" API design standards/rules, am I bound to do exactly what I initially said I was gonna do since consumers of the API are expecting that?  Or do I have the freedom to proceed with the even newer, superceded behaviour as long as it's in the API v2.0.0 documentation and/or release notes?

will your consumers have access to the previous major version? I'd say if you have a version 2 you can change whatever you want. However, if you are replacing v1 with v2, you should try to maintain compatibility as much as you can, because you could cause a breakage on your consumer side. I think any depreciation 'warnings' are just that, warnings, not promises. you are trying to maintain a good relationship with your consumers by generating the warning.  It's not as though you actually made the changes and they have had to react to those yet.

"strict" API designs standards don't really exist in any consistent way across organizations. Whether you CAN remove unused stuff and break your customers systems depends on your relationship with them and expectations you have specifically developed for your system.

"DEPRECATION WARNING: MyClass::ACTIVE is deprecated.  Please use MyClass::ACTIVE_STATUS instead." - did MyClass::ACTIVE_STATUS already exist in v1, so that people migrated to it?

"DEPRECATION WARNING: ::some_method will change behaviour in version 2.0.0" - that's a weird warning. Did you mean the v1 method should no longer be used at all? What would have been the alternative?

@Bergi:  Yes, MyClass::ACTIVE_STATUS already existed in v1, so consumers could have already been using it.  So essentially I'm now wanting to deprecate THAT for another name (say STATUS_ACTIVE) only with no warning since I'm bumping the MAJOR version.

@Bergi:  As far as the method changing behaviour, here's a concrete example.  The method was named first_mi_last and would return Samuel Leroy Jackson with the full middle name.  But many people see mi to mean "middle initial", so the behaviour will change to instead return Samuel L. Jackon.  So the method name stays the same, but returning something different.  So really I'm deprecating the old behaviour, not the name.

@istrasci OK as long ACTIVE_STATUS and ACTIVE are just aliases and have the same value/meaning/behaviour, nothing wrong with that. It would be beneficial if you make a last v1.x.z release that removes the deprecation from the one and adds it to the other, but it's not required. Then in v2, remove the deprecated one (and document it, with the replacement, in your release notes or migration guide).

@istrasci For the method, you should not mark it as deprecated if there's no alternative (as explained in supercat's answer). Add a warning to its documentation if you want, but deprecation means pending removal or at least that it should not be used at all. In the example, you'd rather introduce new (v1) methods first_middle_last and first_minitial_last (or only one of them), then deprecate the confusing one. With v2, you can do breaking changes where you a) remove one method and add the other (though ideally offer both) b) remove the deprecated c) change behaviour of the deprecated

This is an interesting question. From my perspective, while you're releasing a 2.x.y version you are technically able to roll out completely new features but some factors that should be considered are:
advertised
You stated you advertised but you should ask your self did you give customers the allotted timeframe of 3-8 months when put on notice?
rollout
I would look to keep some of the deprecated constants and methods until around version 2.1.y that could allow for a smoother transition from your API customers depending on the extend of usage per those services.
new version
you could technically, with the 2.0.0 version release, do whatever you want but that doesn't mean that it's be the best decision. Another factor to consider if you keep your current constants and methods would that cause conflict with your new features or confusion from a consumer's standpoint.

I would look to keep some of the deprecated constants and methods until around version 2.1.y  This is the small part where "I'm following semver" actually matters, because "making incompatible API changes" (such as removing things) requires a bump in the Major version.  So they couldn't be removed on 2.1.y; it would have to wait until 3.0.0.

Constructs should, when possible, not be deprecated until a viable replacement exists.  What is important after that is that the replacement remain viable.  That doesn't necessarily imply that the suggested replacement be or become the best way of expressing the construct which had been expressed in the "deprecated" code, but it should be recognized as valid as long as people use it.  If something is "deprecated" in favor of a vastly inferior replacement that everyone ignores, it may be better to roll back support for the replacement that's never used than to maintain such support forever, but one should avoid punishing people who replace "deprecated" constructs with recommended replacements.
